# Android wifi hosed after reenabling previous AP via wifimanager

Tags: android, networking, wifi, android-wifi

In my app I connect to a wifi access point using wifiManager using the call described in the docs which tell you to call enableNetwork and pass true as the second parameter to disable other networks:

```
wifiManager.enableNetwork(networkId, true);
```

The side effect is that after I disconnect from the access point, the network that I was previously connected to is still disabled. If you look in the wifi settings it is listed as "Turned off.".

I would like to leave the state of the of the previously connected network as I found it. In order to do that I save off the state of the configured networks before I add my new network and then restore the enabled states afterward disconnecting from my new network:

```
private void saveWifiState() {
    final WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    wasWifiEnabled = wifiManager.isWifiEnabled();
    savedNetworks = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
}

private void restoreSavedWifiState() {
    final WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    if (!wasWifiEnabled) {
        wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
    }
    // When we connected to the specified network we disabled all others.
    // Now restore the enabled state for those that were previously enabled.
    if (savedNetworks != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < savedNetworks.size(); ++i) {
            if (savedNetworks.get(i).status == WifiConfiguration.Status.CURRENT || 
                    savedNetworks.get(i).status == WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED) {
                    wifiManager.enableNetwork(savedNetworks.get(i).networkId, false);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public void disconnect()
{
    final WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    wifiManager.removeNetwork(networkId);
    restoreSavedWifiState();
    wifiManager.saveConfiguration();
}
```

When I run this code on a Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 10.1 (SM-T531) running Android 4.4.2 it leaves the wifi in a bad state. Scanning for APs no longer works. I get "Scan requested (ret=-16) - scan timeout 30 seconds" followed by "Failed to initiate AP scan" from the wpa_supplicant in logcat.

If I got to the wifi settings and try to reconnect the network that I was originally connected to using the saved password it fails with "CTRL-EVENT-ASSOC-REJECT" message from the wpa_supplicant in logcat. I have to reboot or turn on/off airplane mode in order to be able to connect to this network again.

Any ideas on why calling enable network would put the wifi in a bad state? Is there a better way to preserve the original enable state of the other networks?

Comment: After further testing this doesn't seem to be an issue with my code. I can get the wifi into the same bad state from the settings screen in Android by connecting to the first access point, connecting to the second access point and then doing "forget network" on the second access point. At that point I cannot reconnect to the second network again until I reboot or switch on and off airplane mode (which restarts supplicant).